# Creating a pointer to a 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, matrix

I am new to C and spend some hours with arrays and pointers.
Now, I got a specific question I can't really answer by myself.
What are the two variables mat_ptr and ptr which I create in this example and why are they different?
To me it looks like each is an array of pointers storing the pointers to the beginning of the 3 rows of the matrix.

```
int matrix[3][3] = {{0,1,2}, 
                    {0,1,2},
                    {0,1,2}};

int (*mtr_ptr)[3] = matrix;

int *ptr[3];
for (int i=0; i< 3; i++)
{
   ptr[i]=matrix[i];
}
```

I the end, I think ptr ist of type `int **` but what exactly is ptr_ptr?

A pointer to an array of size 3 which is an array of arrays?

Comment: I am sorry, I clearly made a mistake initializing the matrix. 
I just corrected it and hope it didn't make too much extra effort.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
int matrix[5][5] = {{0,1,2,3}, 
                    {0,1,2,3},
                    {0,1,2,3}}
```

is missing a semicolon at the end. When that is fixed, it defines `matrix` to be a 5×5 array (formally an array of 5 arrays of 5 `int`) in which rows 0 to 2 are initialized with four values (0, 1, 2, and 3), leaving element 4 implicitly initialized to zero. Rows 3 to 4 are implicitly initialized to zero.

This code:

```
int (*mtr_ptr)[3] = matrix;
```

defines `mtr_ptr` to be a pointer to an array of 3 `int` and attempts to initialize it with `matrix`. Since `matrix` is an array, it will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, `matrix[0]`. Thus, we have a pointer to an array of 5 `int`. This is not a proper type to initialize a pointer to an array of 3 `int`, so the compiler will complain.

If `matrix` were defined as `int matrix[5][3]` or `int matrix[3][3]`, and the then-excess initializers were removed, then the types in `int (*mtr_ptr)[3] = matrix;` would match, and the compiler would not complain.

This code:

```
int *ptr[3];
for (int i=0; i< 3; i++)
{
   ptr[i]=matrix[i];
}
```

defines an array of 3 pointers to `int` and assigns them values from `matrix[i]`. Since each `matrix[i]` is an array, it will be converted to a pointer to its first element, `matrix[i][0]`. So each `ptr[i]` will be assigned to point to `matrix[i][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

These declarations

```
int matrix[5][5] = {{0,1,2,3}, 
                    {0,1,2,3},
                    {0,1,2,3}}

int (*mtr_ptr)[3] = matrix;
```

do not make a sense. It seems you mean at least the following declarations

```
int matrix[3][4] = {{0,1,2,3}, 
                    {0,1,2,3},
                    {0,1,2,3}};

int (*mtr_ptr)[4] = matrix;
```

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue.** If the array
> object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So the array matrix used in expressions with rare exceptions is converted to pointer to its initial element of the type `int ( * )[4]`.

Thus in this declaration

```
int (*mtr_ptr)[4] = matrix;
```

the pointer `mtr_ptr` is initialized by the address of the first "row" of the array `matrix`.

On the other hand, the expression `matrix[i]` is the i-th element of the array `matrix` that has the type `int[4]`. Such an array used in expression is in turn converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int *`.

In this line

```
int *ptr[3];
```

there is declared an array of three elements of the type `int *`.

And in this loop

```
for (int i=0; i< 3; i++)
{
   ptr[i]=;
}
```

each element of the array of pointers is assigned by the address of the first element of the corresponding "row" of the array `matrix` that ("row") used in the expression `matrix[i]` is implicitly converted to pointer.

Answer (score 0):

First things first.  There is a semi-colon missing from the definition of `matrix`, corrected below:

```
int matrix[5][5] = {{0,1,2,3}, 
                    {0,1,2,3},
                    {0,1,2,3}};
```

Regarding the definition of `mtr_ptr` below:

```
int (*mtr_ptr)[3] = matrix;
```

`mtr_ptr` is declared as a pointer to an array length 3  of `int`s.  However, it is being initialized with an incompatible pointer. `matrix` is an array length 5 of array length 5 of `int`. In the assignment expression above, `matrix` is converted to a pointer to the first element.  The elements of `matrix` have type array length 5 of `int`, so `matrix` is converted to a pointer to array length 5 of `int` with value equivalent to `&matrix[0]`.  Therefore, `mtr_ptr` should be defined as:

```
int (*mtr_ptr)[5] = matrix;
```

or equivalently:

```
int (*mtr_ptr)[5] = &matrix[0];
```

Regarding the code below:

```
int *ptr[3];
for (int i=0; i< 3; i++)
{
   ptr[i]=matrix[i];
}
```

`ptr` is defined as an array length 3 of pointers to `int`. `matrix[i]` is an array length 5 of `int`. In the assignment expression, it is converted to a pointer to its first element. The element type is `int`, so `matrix[i]` is converted to a pointer to `int` equivalent to `&matrix[i][0]`. Therefore, the assignement `ptr[i]=matrix[i];` is equivalent to `ptr[i]=&matrix[i][0];`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the line

```
int (*mtr_ptr)[3] = matrix;
```

the *expression* `matrix` has type "5-element array of 5-element array of `int`".  Since `matrix` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it "decays" to type "pointer to 5-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[5]`, and its value is the address of the first element of `matrix` (same as `&matrix[0]`).

`int (*)[5]` and `int (*)[3]` are different, *incompatible* types, so the compiler should yak at you on that initializer.  You should declare `mtr_ptr` as

```
int (*mtr_ptr)[5] = matrix;
```

Remember that `mtr_ptr` is a *pointer*, not an array - it stores a *single* value.
That single value has type `int (*)[5]`.

By contrast, the expression `matrix[i]` has type "5-element array of `int`"; by the same rule above, that expression "decays" to type "pointer to `int`", or `int *`.  Since each element of your `ptr` array is storing an `int *`, you declare it as

```
int *ptr[3];
```

In this case `ptr` *is* an array, and each element simply stores an `int *`.  That pointer *may* be the address of the first element `matrix[i]`, or it may be a pointer to a single `int` object that isn't part of a larger array, or it may be something else:

```
ptr[0] = matrix[0];
ptr[1] = &i;
...
```

The size of `ptr` does not depend on the size of `matrix` beyond whether or not you want to store the address of all rows or `matrix` or just a subset.